# microtype justification not working on unnumbered section

Tags: microtype, protrusion, section-titles

I am trying to write a paper using \twocolumn and \microtype. Justification looks pretty good in the text, but not in the section (it protrudes into the second column). How can I stop that?
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subscript}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter}
\twocolumn
\section*{Long section header with Saccharomyces cerevisiae}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section*{next section with some name}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Help TeX by inserting `\linebreak`: `Long section header with \linebreak Saccharomyces cerevisiae`. Do this only when the document is in its final form. If it's a standard section, use also the optional argument: `\section[Long section header with Saccharomyces cerevisiae]{Long section header with \linebreak Saccharomyces cerevisiae}`

Answer (score 1):

Allowing hyphenation of words in sectioning headers can be a tricky business and frequently leads to outcomes that require further fine-tuning. Exhibit A: Your working example.

I would like to suggest that you employ ragged-right (aka flush-left) typesetting of sectioning headers *without* permitting hyphenation for the entire document. This may be achieved by inserting the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
```

With these instructions added to your code, the following result is achieved:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%%%\usepackage{ucs}  % are you sure you need this package??
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subscript}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
\begin{document}
%\chapter*{Chapter}
\twocolumn
\section*{Long section header with Saccharomyces cerevisiae}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\section*{next section with some name}
\end{document}
```